# Count columns with a value x at least once

Tags: sql-server, count

Suppose I have this table:

```
 A    B    C
------------
 1    0    0
 0    0    1
 1    0    1
 0    0    0
```

I need the count of columns where 1 occurs (irrespective of the number of times it occurs). So in this example the count would be 2 since it occurs in 2 columns A & C.
How can this be done in SQL server?

Edit: From comments

> Number of columns maybe fixed but unknown

Comment: Are the number of columns fixed or dynamic?

Comment: Its not known. So...ya..dynamic...
Actually its fixed, just not known.

Comment: What a strange requirement. So you don't have a set number of columns to look in? This sounds like dynamic sql to me.

Comment: @stylojack_10 Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like below will give you correct results if number of columns are known, for unknown number of columns this query can be made dynamic.

```
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN colA = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  MAX(CASE WHEN colB = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  MAX(CASE WHEN colC = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  --...
  MAX(CASE WHEN colZ = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountOfColumns
FROM tableT
```

Below is a dynamic query:

```
declare @q varchar(max)

select 
  @q= 'select ' + 
       stuff((
         select 
             '+ MAX(CASE WHEN ' + C.name + '  = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ' 
         from 
            sys.columns C inner join sys.tables T 
              on C.object_id=T.object_id and T.name='tableT'
         for xml path('')),1,1,'') 
        + ' as CountOfColumns FROM tableT'

exec( @q)
```

Comment: How can you make it dynamic?

Comment: @stylojack_10 added dynamic query. Please up-vote if you found it useful.